# Dynamic covariate in lmer not working in emmeans

Tags: r, variables, dynamic, lme4, emmeans

I'm trying to use a dynamic covariate (taken from user input) in an `lmer` model. This works fine, but applying `emmeans` doesn't work any longer.

Example:

```
fit1 = lmer(get(uservar) ~ Intervention + period + sequence + age + (1|ID),
            data = mydata, REML=T)
```

and

```
emmeans(fit1, list(pairwise ~ Intervention), adjust = "tukey")
```

are running without problems.

```
lmer(get(uservar) ~ Intervention + period + sequence + get(covariable) + (1|ID),
     data = mydata, REML=T)
```

with covariable being `"age"` taken from a user input pop-up box also works.

But:

```
emmeans(fit1, list(pairwise ~ Intervention), adjust = "tukey")
```

does not run any longer. It's saying:

> variables have different lengths (found for 'covariable')

But that's not true. If I check `mydata[,covariable]` it has got the same length as the other variables.

Any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 1):

`emmeans()` has to be able to reconstruct the data for the predictor variables to get things like the means of the covariates and levels of the factors. It will work if you save the user-specified data in a data frame and fit the model using that data frame. But keep in mind that if you subsequently change that data frame, say with another user input, it will change the `emmeans()` results even if you don’t refit the model, because it has no way of knowing that the data changed.

Comment: It might work if you add `param = “get”` to the `emmeans` call, but I am not sure. If it does, you’ll have to enter the covariate value a time or two.

Comment: As far as I know `emmeans` doesn't have a params argument. It doesn't work like that. And I don't really get your data.frame workaround. I can add the chosen column to my original dataset (which already includes this column): ´mydata=cbind(mydata, mydata[,c(covariable)]`. How do I access this column in the 'lmer' function? I can use mydata[, c(covariable)] as a name and it works with `fit1<-lmer(get(usevar) ~ Intervention + Periode + Sequenz + maydata[, c(covariable)] + (1|ID), data = mydata, REML=T)`. But emmeans still doesn't run. Can you eloborate?

Comment: I just saw the "..." argument in the emmeans R help. There you can specify data and params. But unfortunately I don't know how to use this "..." option.

Comment: Just create a data frame that already has all of the variables you need. Fit the model to those data, with those variable names. Then use `emmeans` on that model.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a very simple solution:

```
fixed.part <- "get(usevar) ~ Intervention + Periode + Sequenz +  (1|ID)"
random.part <- covariable

fit1 <- lmer(formula(paste(fixed.part, random.part, sep = " + ")), 
 data =testdat_long_cc, REML=TRUE)
emmeans(fit1)
```